# artisan migrate doesn't read my database configuration

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am following this tutorial for beginning Laravel. I have a problem when migrate database.

> php artisan migrate
>
> [PDOException]
>
> could not find driver

I am trying to connect to a slqite database. The database file in the config folder for Laravel:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite')

connections' => [
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

In the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.extension_dir = C:\sqlite\sqlite3.def
```

On the phpinfo() page:

> SQLite3 support    enabled
>
> SQLite3 module version 0.7-dev
>
> SQLite Library 3.8.10.2
>
> Directive  Local Value Master Value
>
> sqlite3.extension_dir  C:\sqlite\sqlite3.def   C:\sqlite\sqlite3.def

>

> pdo_sqlite
>
> PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x  enabled
>
> SQLite Library 3.8.10.2

In the environment section there is this:

> DB_CONNECTION  mysql
>
> DB_DATABASE    homestead

Maybe the last part is a problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure `database_path()` points to your database file.

Comment: The last part is the problem. YOu have the environment pointing at a non-existent definition. Just change those lines in your `.env` to match your needs. `DB_CONNECTION sqlite`. Just delete `DB_DATABASE`

Comment: That worked. Thx!